# What icons are these?

Tags: app-icons

What icons are these?

[image: IMG:]

Not sure if these can be seen well enough.

Answer (score 0):

The one on the left is a notification about a potential power or memory hungry app that could be put to sleep temporarily. The one on the right is probably a suggestion notification from Google Maps.